# Forward audio from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, audio, remote-desktop, forwarding

For example, how do I forward audio from a Ubuntu guest (in Hyper-V) to the Hyper-V host, considering Hyper-V doesn't virtualize audio hardware? There is no pulse client for Windows 10 as far as I know.
But also answer how to forward audio from Linux to a remote client, considering VNC won't do?

Comment: this pages explains how to stream audio to network via pulse https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/

Comment: I suggest you use pulse to output the audio through rtp, and get it in your windows machine through, say, vlc

Comment: That artical doesn't mention anything about Microsoft Windows.

Comment: nope, that is what you do on the ubuntu guest. On windows, just fire up VLC media player to read the stream

Comment: Could that be done to forward from Windows Subsystem for Linux, considering I use VcXSrv for GUI? VcXSrv doesn't forward audio by itself.

Comment: I have not tried it, but as long as you have an ip stack, and the guest ubuntu and the windows host are linked through a (virtual) ip network, it should work

Comment: since technically, it is just forwarding the audio over ip